# wxWidgets wxRichTextCtrl horizontal text wrapping

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a wxRichTextCtrl which keeps wrapping the lines instead of increase the scrollbar size. How can I disable the line wrapping and make it so the horizontal scrollbar grows.

wxWidgets 2.8.11

Answer (score 1):

May be you should try this:

wxTE_DONTWRAP:
Same as wxHSCROLL style: don't wrap at all, show horizontal scrollbar instead.

And other styles look at http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_text_ctrl.html

Comment: Currently I dont think it is doable

Answer (score 0):

According to http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_rich_text_ctrl.html:

> wxRE_MULTILINE:
>
> - The control will be multiline (**mandatory**).

In other words you can't make the wxRichTextCtrl not wrap lines.

Comment: This quote doesn't mean that, although you may be right that it might be impossible.